# Proper way of creating a list of objects

Tags: php, object

I am wondering on the best way to go about creating a list of objects.

Currently, i have a class that deals with orders. In order to retrieve an order it needs to call to an API we were provided with. The API calls are VERY expensive to the point that i could make a call that returns 5000 orders faster than i could make 2 separate calls for 2 separate orders.

Because of this, i built my class to be initialized 2 ways, one way allows me to pass an order number and it initializes itself, but if i pass it an array, it uses the data from the array to create the object.

Now i have functions like `GetOrderList($startDate, $endDate)` that make one call to the API and fill an array full of Order objects that get returned so i can do stuff with them.

This feels 'hacky' to me, so i was wondering if there was an accepted way of doing what i am trying to accomplish while being more OOP.

Note: this is for a personal project that i am using to learn best practices so i would rather hear what i 'should have done' vs 'what i can do from here'

Comment: You're using PHP, the array is the best and only way. Even if you create an object to store the list at the end of the day it will be using an array to do it. Also remember, objects themselves in PHP are just an abstraction of arrays.

Comment: If you have not real limit of how many objects will be created you might consider creating and processing the order objects in a serial manner to keep a small memory footprint. Such strategies can easily become a bottleneck otherwise...

Comment: So this feels 'hacky' to you... May I ask what you mean by that? Why is a simple list not a suitable container to hold your objects if you have no other type of an organisational structure or hierarchy? Can you answer your own question?

Comment: @arkascha I meant the part about using a random function `GetOrderList()` to fill the array. There are like 5 or 6 of these functions that get orders in different ways and i was wondering if there was a way to put these into a class of sorts, or if there was a design guideline that already dealt with this that i can't find.

Comment: Em... you did not mention such randomized creation function at all in your question. Also not that there are several such generators. Maybe you want to add some details to your question? Oh, and... how is decided, which function will be used when?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the `factory design pattern`?

Comment: @arkascha I did not mean random as in RNG but random as in not in a class/not directly related. For example, there is the function above which is actually `GetOrderListByDate($startDate, $endDate)` `GetOrdersInProgress()` `GetOrderReportUpdates()` (which returns all orders that have changed since the call was last made. There are a few other ones like it.

Comment: What about this: you create a static abstract base class and derive a specialized static class for each strategy how you want to fetch the list of objects. Those specialized classes implement the actual fetch function that is declared abstract in the base class. That way you can use any strategy  the same way, you just have to chose which class name to specify in a `call_user_func()` call. This helps to prevent having to specify callbacks or additional arguments, also maintainance details like logging and the like can be kept in a single place (the base class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds fine to me in the case. If you want to be "more correct" (which you can ALWAYS be), then you might want to make a OrderManager object which has a class method to manage collections of Orders. An example call might look like this:

```
<?php
class OrderManager {
    public static function getListByDateRange($startDate, $endDate) {
        // ...
        return $listOfOrders;
    }
}

$orderList = OrderManager::getListByDateRange($startDate, $endDate);
?>
```

This is called the [mediator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern). It gives the flexibility of extending the manager class to have other forms of querying later or if you find yourself doing this a lot, you can make a generic manager class and just specify which types of objects it'll work with in the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

There are pretty much two ways of doing it.  There's the way you're doing it, which by the sounds of what you said, you're basically creating an array (list) of objects.  The OOP way would be to create a "container" class (probably by extending ArrayObject or using SplFixedArray) that holds all of the objects.  Then you could attach an iterator (probably RecursiveArrayIterator) that would loop through all of your stored objects and apply whatever functionality you require.